# Meeting Invitation/Scheduler Module

Tags: 7

I'm looking for a module for Drupal 7 that let's users on a drupal site request invitations to meetings.

So for example, Bob can send a message invitation to Alice and George asking for a 3:30 pm meeting at Starbucks Coffee at the corner of 1st Street and 2nd Street.  THen Alice and George can either accept or decline the invitation.  Bob will have a feed somewhere on his profile page showing what appointments he has coming up.

Is there a module that will do such things?